# How to create a webrtc client for multiple peers to connect to, kind of like a dedicated server

Tags: c++, optimization, webrtc

I am looking to be able to spawn a process from my app that in a sense hosts the webrtc calls. That way all the clients can connect to that one peer. Preferably in c++. If anyone knows how to do this or can point me to some documentation let me know.

Thanks,
Sammy

Comment: This question doesn't make sense - can you clarify what you mean? Are you planning to replicate webrtc functionality in your server?

Comment: @Mikkel sorry, hard to get across my idea. I want to have a dedicated peer running on my server for all other clients to connect too. I want my server to, in a sense, host the call. That way I can control the quality. I hear some apps, like discord, have a custom c++ server running to do just that. I am trying to figure out how to do something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably called a conference, the app - Multipoint Control Unit (MCU). One of the ways to do it in C++: get https://webrtc.org/native-code/ and use the part that deals with WebRTC (basically, a piece of a chrome browser). There is a code example there (in src/webrtc/examples/peerconnection). Takes several weeks/months to get it stable.

Comment: You should checkout Kurento Media server, it has this capabilities, it is written in C.